# Problem with loading lmSupport package in R

Tags: r, r-package, error-messaging, r-library

I am having some difficulties loading a R package `lmSupport`. No problem with the installation but once I try to load it this error message shows up:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘lmSupport’ in .doLoadActions(where, attach):
 error in load action .__A__.1 for package terra: loadModule(module = "spat", what = TRUE, env = ns, loadNow = TRUE): Unable to load module "spat": function 'Rcpp_precious_remove' not provided by package 'Rcpp'
In addition: Warning message:
package ‘lmSupport’ was built under R version 4.0.5
```

What is this error message about? Is it something to do with `Rcpp`? How can I resolve this? Thank you for any help!

Comment: What is your R version? Try running `update.packages(checkBuilt = TRUE)`?

Comment: @Roland Thank you. My R version is 4.0.2. After running your code and updating the packages, I still have the same error

Comment: Update R. Reinstall Rcpp and terra.

Comment: Thank you @Roland. I was able to solve that problem!